# How to get number of collections that are stored in a Firestore document?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My firestore structure looks like this. There is a collection mychats that consists of documents that also consists of different collections. Is there any way i could get the number of collections stored in every document
[image]

Comment: Found the solution here https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166

Comment: That would be a bad solution, this is an example of the XY problem where you are asking on how to solve a problem that you shouldn't be facing, since it's the wrong approach. I recommend you read Doug's solution since you'd be better off using static names instead of random IDs as the collection name. Doing it would prevent you from needing to list the sub-collections, which is far from ideal. If you only need to know the amount of documents you should use an attribute as a counter, as Doug suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to list or count subcollections using any of the Firestore web or mobile SDKs.  You should probably instead keep track of anything you need with your own code that writes to some document that maintains any required counts.

Note that subcollections are not really stored "within" a document.  They are merely nested under that document's name.  The screenshot you show here actually has missing documents, as you can see from the fact that they are listed in italics in the console.

If you are willing to make a call to a backend, you could use a method like [listCollections()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#listCollections) to get a list of subcollections nested under a document.  The ability to list collections is only available with server SDKs, and not available to web and mobile client SDKs.

I will say that having randomly generated IDs for collection is probably not the best database design.  You're probably better off using static names for collections so that you don't have to worry about listing them.  If you instead put your randomly named items as documents within a subcollections, you can list them with no problem simply by querying the subcollection.

Comment: These are not randomly generated id these are the uid of the firebase users that have signedup with our app.

Comment: They are still randomly generated by firebase auth.  I would still choose to store things differently in order to enable the queries you want to perform.  It's up to you, but what you're doing now makes things more difficult.